# TeX-function for writing R-functions

Tags: r

I'm working on an introductory course for the R-language in Latex, so I'm trying to write a Latex function that displays the R-function. This is what I've got:

```
\makeatletter  
\newcommand{\fun}[3]{  
    \begin{tcolorbox}[top = 0mm, bottom = 0mm, left = 0mm, right = 0mm, colback=green!5,colframe=vubgreen,title=#3]  
    \begin{tabular}{p{.2\textwidth}p{.04\textwidth}p{.68\textwidth}}  
    {\tt#1(}\\\@for\x:=#2\do{\x\\}{\tt$\quad$)}  
    \end{tabular}  
  \end{tcolorbox}}  
\makeatother
```

So, this function accepts three parameters: the name of the R-function, a list of R-parameters, and a description, with each R-parameter:

```
\renewcommand{\arg}[3][]{  
  {\tt$\quad$#2}&&#3}
```

So you can write for example:

```
\fun{hist}  
  {  
    \arg{x}{Vector.},  
    \arg{freq = TRUE}{Use absolute frequencies.}  
  }  
  {Draw a histogram.}
```

Now I'm having a few small problems to get it completely right:
- The opening round bracket has to be on the same line as the first parameter (so the line under the first function.
- The closing round bracket has to be right behind the last parameter (NOT behind the description of the parameter).
- Behind each parameter there has to be a comma, except after the last one.
- However: if a function has no parameters, opening and closing round bracket have to be on the same line as the name of the function.

Packages used (not all relevant for this example):

```
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{enumerate}        
\usepackage{answers}      
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{tcolorbox}  
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}  
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}  
\usepackage{anysize}  
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}  
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\usepackage{longtable}
```

I think this seems like a challenge, even for the TeXperts over here. All help is really appreciated!

Comment: If you have a block of code, you need to indent it by 4 spaces (or select it and click the Code Button `{}`) rather than add backticks before/after the code. Welcome!

Comment: Writing about R in TeX you should seriously consider `knitr` (http://yihui.name/knitr/), which allows you to write _executable_ R in your document. That will guarantee the semantic correctness of your code as well as its proper prettyprinting.

Comment: I've heard about knitr, but as everything is written in a different way I prefer not to switch.

Comment: @m00se "everything is written in a different way" What? Is just write LaTeX and just write R, nothing new except that you must say when R start with a line with `<<>>=` (optionally with many very useful parameters) and where R end (a line with only `@`)  or alternatively, to just print the value or some R object of some function, you can use a  `\Sexpr{}` like  `\Sexpr{round(log(pi),1)}` (that will print "1.1") . There any examples of use of knitr in this site. You do not know what you will lose if you persist in your *wrong* belief ...